# AttributeError: module 'api.db' has no attribute 'Model' on Flask

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Hello I have the following folder structure

```
    .
    ├── api
    │   ├── users
    │   │   ├── __init__.py
    │   │   ├── model.py
    │   │   └── routes.py
│   ├── |__init__.py
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── requirements.txt
    └── server.py
```

In `api.__init__.py` I have the following code:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from api import users
from flask_restful import Api

db = SQLAlchemy()


def create_app(env):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    db.init_app(app)
    api = Api(app)
    users.register_routes(api)
    return app
```

and in `users/model.py` I have the following code:

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String
from .. import db

class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
...
```

And in `server.py` I have the following code:

```
import os

from api import create_app

app = create_app(os.getenv("ENV"))
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(port=os.getenv("PORT"), debug=os.getenv("DEBUG")=='True')
```

The problem is that when I execute server.py I have the following error:

> AttributeError: module 'api.db' has no attribute 'Model'

How can I solve this error?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure `db` is not overridden inside `api/__init__.py` ? try to confirm it with a quick `print(db)` right after `from .. import db`. Attaching the full exception will be helpful too.

Comment: The print return the following: <module 'api.db' (namespace)>, updated with all code of api.__init__

Comment: That's not right, i think it should be `<SQLAlchemy engine=None>` so my guess it's overridden with something else. Probably you have a `api/db.py` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i would suggest you making some changes to the structure of your project to avoid circular import issue and prefer importing your app as package not as a module and also as a good practice  `__init __.py` is kept just for `import` and some `metadata` like `__author__` and `__version__`

```
api

  .. errors (blueprint)
    .. __init__.py
    .. routes.py


  .. users (blueprint)
    .. __init__.py
    .. model.py
    .. routes.py

  .. extensions.py

  .. __init__.py
  .. app.py (here where your define "create_app()" function)


server.py
requirements.txt
```

in `api/users/__init __.py`:

```
from .routes import bp
```

in `api/users/models.py`:

```
from api.extensions import db

# from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String  # You don't need this since you already imported the db oject 

class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)  # here 
...
```

in `api/users/routes.py`:

```
from flask import Blueprint, request, jsonify ..

from api.extensions import db  # maybe you need it here
from .models import User  # Your model


bp = Blueprint('users', __name__)  # instantiate your 'users' Blueprint


@bp.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST']) 
def index():

    ..
    
    return jsonify(..)
```

in `/api/extensions.py`, define the `Flask` extensions needed for your app

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
..

db = SQLAlchemy()
..
```

in `/api/__init __.py`:

```
from .app import create_app
```

in `/api/app.py`:

```
from flask import Flask
..

def create_app(config_object):
    """Create a Flask application using the app factory pattern."""

    app = Flask(__name__)

    """Load configuration."""
    # app.config.from_object(CONFIGS[config_object])  # an example 

..

    """Init app extensions."""
    from .extensions import db
    db.init_app(app)

..

    """Register blueprints."""
    from .errors import bp as errors_bp
    app.register_blueprint(errors_bp)

    from .users import bp as users_bp
    app.register_blueprint(users_bp, url_prefix='/users')

..
    
    return app
```

in `/server.py`:

```
import os

from api import create_app


app = create_app(os.getenv("ENV", "development"))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(port=os.getenv("PORT", 5000), debug=os.getenv("DEBUG", True)
```

Comment: Great answer, can you tell me where I did circular imports?

Comment: i just mean, since flask is un-opinionated framework, with good project structure you can avoid many issues (circular imports -  not your case - ), make your app maintainable and easy to debug and extensible.

Comment: if you want to register routes just prefer `@bp.route()` decorator in `users/routes.py` or at the bottom of `users/routes.py` you can call `bp.add_url_rule('/', 'index', index)`